I am not able to type anything after execution for specific code
I want to run my nodemon file for that i have to type in the terminal but i am not able to do so. Here is the screen shot for the same.

So, In my other codes i can edit in terminal like cpp and c language but the codes include some server like or you can say webdev related codes it unable to write something so that's a problem
Help me for the same so that i haven't to restart the port again and again.

Please always replace images of code with a text-based [mre]

Also, this issue doesn't seem to be programming specific. Instead it looks like you want to run nodemon in a background process? If so, take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/106351/running-programs-in-the-background-from-terminal

Hit ctrl+c or ctrl+break in the terminal to stop the node process you've started?

Click the '+' sign at the top-right of the terminal to open a second terminal. In that you can start your nodemon. This way both of your processes - nodemon and server will be running.
